# Merging two data frames when the column names are different

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge a couple of excel files into one big excel file.
The problem is that the column names in those files are different, though the data is the same.
In other words- for the same cell value, the column is once called "a" and once "b".
When I combine those files, instead of putting all the data under the same column names it puts the data from each file into different columns. So the way it looks in the united excel is far from great.

How can I check if the two columns share the same name and afterward combine the data so it would go under the same column?
Here are the column names-

**file1.columns**

```
Index(['Day', 'Month', 'Year', 'Station', 'Sample ID', 'Syn Conc. (#/mL)',
       'Euk Conc. (#/mL)', 'Pro Conc. (#/mL)', **'Hetero Bact. Conc. (#/mL)'**,
       'FCS Syn / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'FCS Euk / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'FCS Pro / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Syn / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Euk / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Pro / SCS beads medians ratio'],
      dtype='object')
```

**file2.columns**

```
Index(['Day', 'Month', 'Year ', 'Station ', 'Depth (m)', 'Syn Conc. (#/mL)',
       'Euk Conc. (#/mL)', 'Pro Conc. (#/mL)', 'Pro-Violet Conc. (#/mL)',
       **'Hetero Bacteria**', 'FCS Syn / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'FCS Euk / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'FCS Pro / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'FCS Pro-Violet / FCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Syn / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Euk / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Pro / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'SCS Pro-Violet / SCS beads medians ratio',
       'Red FL Syn / Red FL beads medians ratio',
       'Red FL Euk / Red FL beads medians ratio',
       'Red FL Pro / Red FL beads medians ratio',
       'Red FL Pro-Violet / Red FL beads medians ratio',
       'Orange FL Syn / Orange FL beads medians ratio', 'Analysis Date'],
      dtype='object')
```

Thanks in advance guys and gals,
Karin :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your column before the merge. Assuming you want to keep the format of the first dataframe and the second one is named `df2`:

```
df2.rename({'Hetero Bacteria': 'Hetero Bact. Conc. (#/mL)'})
```

Note that the operation is not in place, so either do:

```
df2 = df2.rename({'Hetero Bacteria': 'Hetero Bact. Conc. (#/mL)'})
```

or use the renamed dataframe in your merge command (I assume it is `concat`):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.rename({'Hetero Bacteria': 'Hetero Bact. Conc. (#/mL)'})])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
but it seems that even though the column names are identical, it still create another column (with the same name...) and puts the values there. I can't seem to understand why it adds the same columns to a separate one :-(

Comment: Please provide a minimal example then (two small dataframes, the command you use to merge, and the expected output that you don't manage to get)